# In a trapezium ABCD, AB||CD, angle B = 1/2D. If AD = q and DC = p, find AB.

Tags: plane-geometry

In a trapezium $ABCD$, $AB||CD$, angle$B$ = $\frac{1}{2}D$. If $AD = q$ and $DC = p$, find $AB$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the bisector of angle D, which must be parallel to BC to meet AB at X. Triangle AXD is isosceles, and XBCD is a parallelogram,so $AX + XB = AB= p+q$